# When I filter I can delete and update records through pages perfectly fine , but i can't delete/update on 2 and up pages on my today inserted records

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 3 days and not figuring out why I can not delete / update record on 2 and up pages. It works fine on the first page. When I filter it works fine through pages. Can you help me please to find the error?

I added some debugging prints , and the problem is the index is counting good but the id list is not populated with the ids of the second page , just with id of first page.

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk
import datetime
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Listbox, Scrollbar, StringVar, END
import backend as be
from my_calendar import PersonalizedCalendar

# frontend
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk
import datetime
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Listbox, Scrollbar, StringVar, END
import backend as be
from my_calendar import PersonalizedCalendar

class PatientPagination:
    def __init__(self, doctor_id):
        self.doctor_id = doctor_id
        self.page_size = 10
        self.current_page = 1
        self.filtered_patients = []
        self.all_patients = []

def update_filtered_patients(self, filtered_patients):
    self.filtered_patients = filtered_patients
    self.current_page = 1

def fetch_patients(self):
    start_index = (self.current_page - 1) * self.page_size
    end_index = start_index + self.page_size
    print("Start Index:", start_index)  # Debugging statement
    print("End Index:", end_index)      # Debugging statement
    print("Filtered Patients:", self.filtered_patients)  # Debugging statement
    print("All Patients:", self.all_patients)            # Debugging statement
    if self.filtered_patients:
        return self.filtered_patients[start_index:end_index]
    else:
        return self.all_patients[start_index:end_index]

def total_patients_count(self):
    if self.filtered_patients:
        return len(self.filtered_patients)  # Return the count of filtered patients if they exist
    elif self.all_patients:
        return len(self.all_patients)  # Return the count of all patients if filtered patients don't exist
    else:
        return 0  # Return 0 if there are no patients at all

def total_pages(self):
    total_patients = self.total_patients_count()
    return (total_patients + self.page_size - 1) // self.page_size

def prev_page(self):
    if self.current_page > 1:
        self.current_page -= 1
        return True
    return False

def next_page(self):
    total_pages = self.total_pages()
    if self.current_page < total_pages:
        self.current_page += 1
        return True
    return False

def __init__(self, doctor_id, doctor_name, role):
    super().__init__()
    self.selected_start_date = None  # Variable to store the selected start date
    self.selected_end_date = None  # Variable to store the selected end date
    # Determine screen width and height
    screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
    self.role = role  # Store the role attribute
    self.crud_window_open = False  # Initialize the flag

    # Calculate the window size
    window_width = int(screen_width * 0.99)
    window_height = int(screen_height * 0.88)

    # Set the window size and position
    self.geometry(
        f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{int((screen_width - window_width) / 2)}+{int((screen_height - window_height) / 2)}")

    self.title(f"Patient Management App")
    self.configure(bg='#f0f0f0')  # Set background color

    # Initialize patient_ids list
    self.patient_ids = []
    self.doctor_id = doctor_id
    self.doctor_name = doctor_name
    self.role = role  # Store the role
    self.selected_start_date = None  # Variable to store the selected start date
    self.selected_end_date = None  # Variable to store the selected end date
    self.pagination = PatientPagination(doctor_id)  # Initialize PatientPagination instance


    # Add a new attribute to store today's date
    self.today_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()

    # Frame to contain entry fields and button for adding patient
    self.entry_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='#f0f0f0')
    self.entry_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)

    if role != 'admin':
        # Entry field for Name
        self.name_label = tk.Label(
            self.entry_frame,
            text="Name:",
            font=("Arial", 14, "bold"),
            bg='#f0f0f0',  # Background color
            fg='#333333'  # Text color
        )
        self.name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.name_entry = tk.Entry(
            self.entry_frame,
            font=("Arial", 12)
        )
        self.name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        # Entry field for Surname
        self.surname_label = tk.Label(
            self.entry_frame,
            text="Surname:",
            font=("Arial", 14, "bold"),
            bg='#f0f0f0',  # Background color
            fg='#333333'  # Text color
        )
        self.surname_label.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.surname_entry = tk.Entry(
            self.entry_frame,
            font=("Arial", 12)
        )
        self.surname_entry.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

        # Entry field for Diagnosis
        self.diagnosis_label = tk.Label(
            self.entry_frame,
            text="Diagnosis:",
            font=("Arial", 14, "bold"),
            bg='#f0f0f0',  # Background color
            fg='#333333'  # Text color
        )
        self.diagnosis_label.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.diagnosis_entry = tk.Text(
            self.entry_frame,
            font=("Arial", 12),
            height=5,
            width=50
        )
        self.diagnosis_entry.grid(row=0, column=5, padx=10, pady=10)

        # Add Patient button
        self.add_patient_button = tk.Button(
            self.entry_frame,
            text="Add Patient",
            font=("Arial", 14, "bold"),
            bg='#4caf50',  # Background color
            fg='white',  # Text color
            command=self.add_patient,
            width=12  # Set a fixed width
        )
        self.add_patient_button.grid(row=0, column=6, padx=10, pady=10)

    # Frame to contain entry fields and button for filtering
    self.filter_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='#f0f0f0')
    self.filter_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)

    # Entry field for Name filter
    self.filter_name_label = tk.Label(
        self.filter_frame,
        text="Name:",
        font=("Arial", 14, "bold"),
        bg='#f0f0f0',  # Background color
        fg='#333333'  # Text color
    )
    self.filter_name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    self.filter_name_entry = tk.Entry(
        self.filter_frame,
        font=("Arial", 12)
    )
    self.filter_name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    # Entry field for Surname filter
    self.filter_surname_label = tk.Label(
        self.filter_frame,
        text="Surname:",
        font=("Arial", 14, "bold"),
        bg='#f0f0f0',  # Background color
        fg='#333333'  # Text color
    )
    self.filter_surname_label.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
    self.filter_surname_entry = tk.Entry(
        self.filter_frame,
        font=("Arial", 12)
    )
    self.filter_surname_entry.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

    # Button to show calendar for Start Date filter
    self.show_start_date_calendar_button = tk.Button(
        self.filter_frame,
        text="Select Start Date",
        font=("Arial", 14, "bold"),
        bg='#2196f3',  # Background color
        fg='white',  # Text color
        command=self.show_start_date_calendar
    )
    self.show_start_date_calendar_button.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

    # Label to show selected Start Date
    self.selected_start_date_label = tk.Label(
        self.filter_frame,
        text="",
        font=("Arial", 12),
        bg='#f0f0f0',  # Background color
        fg='#333333'  # Text color
    )
    self.selected_start_date_label.grid(row=0, column=5, padx=10, pady=10)

    # Button to show calendar for End Date filter
    self.show_end_date_calendar_button = tk.Button(
        self.filter_frame,
        text="Select End Date",
        font=("Arial", 14, "bold"),
        bg='#2196f3',  # Background color
        fg='white',  # Text color
        command=self.show_end_date_calendar
    )
    self.show_end_date_calendar_button.grid(row=0, column=6, padx=10, pady=10)

    # Label to show selected End Date
    self.selected_end_date_label = tk.Label(
        self.filter_frame,
        text="",
        font=("Arial", 12),
        bg='#f0f0f0',  # Background color
        fg='#333333'  # Text color
    )
    self.selected_end_date_label.grid(row=0, column=7, padx=10, pady=10)

    # Filter button
    self.filter_button = tk.Button(
        self.filter_frame,
        text="Filter",
        font=("Arial", 14, "bold"),
        bg='#4caf50',  # Background color
        fg='white',  # Text color
        command=self.filter_patients,
        width=12  # Set a fixed width
    )
    self.filter_button.grid(row=0, column=8, padx=10, pady=10)

    # Button to clear filtering
    self.clear_filter_button = tk.Button(
        self.filter_frame,
        text="Clear Filter",
        font=("Arial", 14, "bold"),
        bg='#f44336',  # Background color
        fg='white',  # Text color
        command=self.clear_filter_fields,
        width=12  # Set a fixed width
    )
    self.clear_filter_button.grid(row=0, column=9, padx=10, pady=10)

    # Create Treeview widget
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=("Name", "Surname", "Diagnosis", "Date"), show="headings",
                             style="Custom.Treeview")
    self.tree.bind("<Double-1>", self.on_tree_double_click)
    self.tree.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    # Define custom style for Treeview
    self.style = ttk.Style()
    self.style.configure("Custom.Treeview.Heading", font=("Arial", 14, "bold"))  # Style for column headings
    self.style.configure("Custom.Treeview", font=("Arial", 14), padding=10)  # Adjust padding to increase space
    self.style.map("Custom.Treeview", foreground=[('selected', '#ffffff')], background=[('selected', '#0078d7')])
    self.style.map("Custom.Treeview", rowheight=[('selected', 100)])  # Increase row height

    # Adjust column headings

    self.tree.heading("Name", text="Name", anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.tree.heading("Surname", text="Surname", anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.tree.heading("Diagnosis", text="Diagnosis", anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.tree.heading("Date", text="Date", anchor=tk.CENTER)

    # Adjust column widths

    self.tree.column("Name", width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.tree.column("Surname", width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.tree.column("Diagnosis", width=200, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.tree.column("Date", width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    # Adjust row spacing
    self.tree.tag_configure("spaced")  # Set spacing between rows

    self.patient_count_label = tk.Label(
        self,
        text="Total Patients: 0",
        font=("Arial", 12),
        bg='#f0f0f0',  # Background color
        fg='#333333'  # Text color
    )
    self.patient_count_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)

    # Pagination variables
    self.page_size = 10  # Number of patients per page
    self.current_page = 1  # Current page number

    # Navigation buttons
    self.prev_button = tk.Button(self, text="Prev", command=self.prev_page)
    self.prev_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)

    self.next_button = tk.Button(self, text="Next", command=self.next_page)
    self.next_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)
    # Update patient list initially
    self.update_patients_list()

    # Logout button
    self.logout_button = tk.Button(
        self,
        text="Logout",
        font=("Arial", 14, "bold"),
        bg='#f44336',  # Background color
        fg='white',  # Text color
        command=self.logout
    )
    self.logout_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=10, pady=10)

    # Doctor name label
    self.doctor_name_label = tk.Label(
        self,
        text=f"Logged in as Dr. {doctor_name}",
        font=("Arial", 12),
        bg='#f0f0f0',  # Background color
        fg='#333333'  # Text color
    )
    self.doctor_name_label.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=10, pady=10)

    if role == 'admin':
        # Button to open a window to delete doctors
        self.delete_doctor_button = tk.Button(
            self,
            text="Delete Doctor",
            font=("Arial", 14, "bold"),
            bg='#f3212d',  # Background color
            fg='white',  # Text color
            command=self.open_delete_doctor_window
        )
        self.delete_doctor_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)

    if role == 'admin':
        # Add UI elements for updating doctor password
        self.update_password_button = tk.Button(
            self,
            text="Update Doctor Password",
            font=("Arial", 14, "bold"),
            bg='#0a6ebd',
            fg='white',
            command=self.open_update_password_window
        )
        self.update_password_button.pack(pady=10)

    # Update patient count label
    self.populate_patients_list()  # Populate patient list
    self.update_patient_count_label()
def update_patients_list(self):
    # Fetch patients based on pagination from PatientPagination instance
    patients = self.pagination.fetch_patients()

    # Print the fetched patients for debugging
    print("Fetched patients:", patients)

    # Clear previous entries
    print("Clearing previous entries in the Treeview.")
    self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())

    if patients:
        # Populate the Treeview with patient data for the current page
        for i, patient in enumerate(patients):
            self.tree.insert("", "end", values=(patient[2], patient[3], patient[4], patient[5]))

            # Add empty rows between data rows for spacing
            if i < len(patients) - 1:
                self.tree.insert("", "end", values=("", "", "", ""), tags=("spaced",))

        # Add spacing rows
        self.add_spacing_rows(len(patients))

        # Update patient count label to show the current page and total pages
        total_pages = self.pagination.total_pages()
        total_patients = self.pagination.total_patients_count()
        self.patient_count_label.config(
            text=f"Page {self.pagination.current_page}/{total_pages}, Total Patients: {total_patients}")
        print("Patient list updated successfully.")
    else:
        print("No patients found")  # Debugging print
def prev_page(self):
    if self.pagination.prev_page():
        # If previous page exists, update patient list
        print("Moving to the previous page.")
        self.update_patients_list()
    else:
        print("No previous page available.")

def next_page(self):
    if self.pagination.next_page():
        # If next page exists, update patient list
        print("Moving to the next page.")
        self.update_patients_list()
    else:
        print("No next page available.")
def populate_patients_list(self):
    # Clear previous entries
    print("Clearing previous entries.")
    self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())

    # Fetch patients added today based on the doctor's access level
    if self.doctor_id == -1:
        # Fetch patients from all doctors
        patients_added_today, today_patients_count = be.get_patients_added_today_all()
    else:
        # Fetch patients added today by the currently logged-in doctor
        patients_added_today, today_patients_count = be.get_patients_added_today(self.doctor_id)

    # Update the pagination object with the fetched patients
    print("Updating pagination object with fetched patients.")
    self.pagination.all_patients = patients_added_today

    # Pagination
    total_pages = (len(patients_added_today) + self.page_size - 1) // self.page_size
    start_index = (self.pagination.current_page - 1) * self.page_size
    end_index = min(start_index + self.page_size, len(patients_added_today))
    patients_on_page = patients_added_today[start_index:end_index]

    # Clear any previous patient IDs
    print("Clearing any previous patient IDs.")
    self.patient_ids = []

    # Populate the Treeview with patient data and spacing
    for i, patient in enumerate(patients_on_page):
        patient_id = patient[0]
        self.patient_ids.append(patient_id)
        # Ensure the order of values matches the order of columns in the Treeview
        self.tree.insert("", "end", values=(patient[2], patient[3], patient[4], patient[5]))

        # Add empty rows between data rows for spacing
        if i < len(patients_on_page) - 1:
            self.tree.insert("", "end", values=("", "", "", ""), tags=("spaced",))

    # Print today's patients count
    print("Today's patients count:", today_patients_count)

    # Update patient count label to show the current page, total pages, and today's patients count
    print("Updating patient count label.")
    self.update_patient_count_label(today_patients_count)

def update_patient_count_label(self, today_patients_count=None):
    if today_patients_count is not None:
        total_pages = (today_patients_count + self.page_size - 1) // self.page_size
        print("Updating patient count label with today's patients count.")
        self.patient_count_label.config(
            text=f"Page {self.current_page}/{total_pages}, Total Patients: {today_patients_count}")
    else:
        total_patients = len(self.pagination.all_patients)  # Use pagination data
        total_pages = (total_patients + self.page_size - 1) // self.page_size
        print("Updating patient count label with total patients count.")
        self.patient_count_label.config(
            text=f"Page {self.current_page}/{total_pages}, Today Patients: {total_patients}")

def filter_patients(self):
    # Get filter criteria
    filter_name = self.filter_name_entry.get().strip().lower()
    filter_surname = self.filter_surname_entry.get().strip().lower()
    start_date = self.selected_start_date
    end_date = self.selected_end_date

    # Debugging print to show filter criteria
    print("Filter criteria - Name:", filter_name, "Surname:", filter_surname, "Start Date:", start_date,
          "End Date:", end_date)

    # Check if any filtering criteria are provided
    if not (filter_name or filter_surname or (start_date and end_date)):
        print("No filter criteria provided. Returning.")  # Debugging print
        return  # Return if no filtering criteria are provided

    # Fetch patients based on name filter
    patients = be.get_patients_by_name(self.doctor_id, filter_name)

    # Filter patients based on surname filter
    filtered_patients = [patient for patient in patients if
                         (filter_surname in patient[3].lower() if filter_surname else True)]

    # Apply date range filter if both start date and end date are selected
    if start_date is not None and end_date is not None:
        # Convert selected dates to datetime objects for comparison
        start_datetime = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date(),
                                                   datetime.datetime.min.time())
        end_datetime = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date(),
                                                 datetime.datetime.min.time())
        # Filter patients based on registration date within the selected range
        filtered_patients = [patient for patient in filtered_patients if
                             start_datetime <= datetime.datetime.strptime(patient[5].split()[0],
                                                                          "%Y-%m-%d") <= end_datetime]

    # Debugging print to show the number of patients found after filtering
    print("Number of patients found after filtering:", len(filtered_patients))

    # Clear previous entries
    self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())
    self.patient_ids = []

    if filtered_patients:
        # Populate the Treeview with filtered patient data
        for i, patient in enumerate(filtered_patients):
            # Ensure the order of values matches the order of columns in the Treeview
            self.tree.insert("", "end", values=(patient[2], patient[3], patient[4], patient[5]))

            # Add patient ID to the list
            self.patient_ids.append(patient[0])  # Add patient ID to the list

            # Add empty rows between data rows for spacing
            if i < len(filtered_patients) - 0.5:
                self.tree.insert("", "end", values=("", "", "", ""), tags=("spaced",))
    else:
        print("No patients found matching the criteria.")  # Debugging print
        # Update patient count label even if no patients are found
        self.update_patient_count_label(0)

        # No need to update pagination or patient list if no patients are found
        return

    # Update patient count label
    self.update_patient_count_label()

    # Update pagination to consider the filtered patients
    self.pagination.update_filtered_patients(filtered_patients)

    # Set current page to 1 after filtering
    self.pagination.current_page = 1

    # Update patients list after pagination is updated
    self.update_patients_list()
def on_tree_double_click(self, event):
    if not self.crud_window_open:
        item = self.tree.selection()
        if item:
            item = item[0]
            name = self.tree.item(item, "values")[0]
            surname = self.tree.item(item, "values")[1]
            diagnosis = self.tree.item(item, "values")[2]
            index = self.tree.index(item) // 2  # Adjust index calculation considering the spacing

            # Calculate the index relative to the current page
            start_index = (self.pagination.current_page - 1) * self.page_size
            index += start_index

            # Debugging statements
            print("Selected item:", item)
            print("Name:", name)
            print("Surname:", surname)
            print("Diagnosis:", diagnosis)
            print("Index:", index)
            print("Patient IDs:", self.patient_ids)  # Add debugging statement for patient IDs

            if 0 <= index < len(self.patient_ids):
                patient_id = self.patient_ids[index]

                # Fetch the doctor's username who added this patient
                doctor_username = be.get_doctor_username(patient_id)

                # Open the CRUD window with patient details
                CRUDWindow(self, self.role, name, surname, diagnosis, patient_id, doctor_username)

                # Set the flag to indicate that a CRUD window is open
                self.crud_window_open = True
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Index out of range")
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "A CRUD window is already open")

def on_crud_window_close(self, event):
    # Reset the flag when the CRUD window is closed
    self.crud_window_open = False

def update_patient_list(self, deleted_index):
    # Calculate the index of the patient being deleted based on the current page
    start_index = (self.pagination.current_page - 1) * self.page_size
    patient_index = start_index + deleted_index

    # Debugging print to show the index of the deleted patient
    print("Deleted patient index:", patient_index)

    # Remove the patient ID from the list
    del self.patient_ids[patient_index]

    # Debugging print to show the patient IDs after deletion
    print("Patient IDs after deletion:", self.patient_ids)

    # Reindex patient IDs in the treeview
    for i in range(len(self.patient_ids)):
        item = self.tree.get_children()[i]  # Adjust index considering pagination
        # Debugging print to show the item being updated
        print("Updating item:", item, "with value:", i + 1)
        self.tree.item(item, values=(i + 1,))
```

Comment: When posting on stack overflow, it is common practice to reduce the code to the minimum possible amount of code. Please could you do this so it is easier for people to help

Comment: Please [edit] your question to reduce the code to a [mre].

Comment: Fix the indentation issue as well.